# I want to know if changing your Route53 routing policy will cause downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am a junior developer studying aws.

I am using it to look at the ALB as an A record on Route53.

A routing policy is used as a simple routing policy.

Will there be any downtime in changing the record option from a simple routing policy to a weighted routing policy?

> I tested it by blowing curl using while, but I can't figure out how it works in the process of actually changing the option, so I ask a question!

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the DNS records shouldn't result in downtime at all as long as the records point to servers/services that can handle requests.

DNS records are cached at multiple levels (client and/or multiple levels of resolvers), so getting a response shouldn't be a problem while you switch over. In fact, a bigger problem is that clients will most likely use the outdated information for a while due to the TTL setting.

DNS only *really* matters on initial contact anyway, afterwards the client talks directly to the server and any changes to DNS shouldn't have an impact.

Comment: @bob Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you, so others know that this question is resolved ;-)